# Incidence correspondence as a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The incidence correspondence is $\Sigma=\{(x,L) \mid x\in L\}\subset \mathbf{P}^n\times\mathbf{Gr}(k,n)$. What I ask myself is what this actually means, after all the underlying set of the fibre product is not the cartesian product?
So how should I interpret this?

Comment: @Eoin: while these notes are interesting, I do not see how it explains this

Comment: What is your definition of the Grassmannian as a scheme? Once you know that and its universal property, the interpretation should be clear.

Comment: @Mohan I just came across this question and I find it interesting. Basically the answer is that $P^n\times Gr(k,n)$ represents a "product functor", and the incidence correspondence represents a subfunctor of this product functor. is this correct?

Comment: Not merely a functor, they are representable functors.